# replace values for NA per related columns in r

Tags: r

I am trying to clean a dataset like this:

```
       date                pm2.5 pm2.5_flag  NEPH NEPH_flag NEPH_RH NEPH_RH_flag
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       
 1 2020-02-04 00:00:00  26.8 G           1.02 G            35.8 G           
 2 2020-02-04 00:01:00  27.1 G           0.98 G            35.7 G           
 3 2020-02-04 00:02:00  27.2 G           0.95 G            35.8 G           
 4 2020-02-04 00:03:00  27.0 G           0.94 G            35.7 G           
 5 2020-02-04 00:04:00  26.8 G           0.93 G            35.6 G           
 6 2020-02-04 00:05:00  26.7 G           0.94 G            35.6 G           
 7 2020-02-04 00:06:00  26.9 G           0.92 G            35.7 G           
 8 2020-02-04 00:07:00  27.0 G           0.83 G            35.4 G           
 9 2020-02-04 00:08:00  27.4 G           0.81 G            35.4 G           
10 2020-02-04 00:09:00  27.8 G           0.72 G            35.0 G
```

It has the data value in one column and next to it a column with a flag associated with that value. I want to remove all other flags different than "G" from that column and replace the value of the related column by NA.

For example if my row is

```
date                pm2.5 pm2.5_flag  NEPH NEPH_flag NEPH_RH NEPH_RH_flag
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       
 1 2020-02-04 00:00:00  26.8 G           1.02 G            35.8 G           
 2 2020-02-04 00:01:00  27.1 C           0.98 BIA          35.7 G 
10 2020-02-04 00:09:00  27.8 C           0.72 G            35.0 G
```

I want to get

```
  date                pm2.5 pm2.5_flag  NEPH NEPH_flag NEPH_RH NEPH_RH_flag
   <dttm>              <dbl> <chr>      <dbl> <chr>       <dbl> <chr>       
 1 2020-02-04 00:00:00  26.8 G           1.02 G            35.8 G           
 2 2020-02-04 00:01:00  NA   NA          NA   NA           35.7 G 
10 2020-02-04 00:09:00  NA   NA          0.72 G            35.0 G
```

Comment: I see a `BIA`  which is not found in input dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create pairs of columns with `'flag'` and it's associated corresponding value. Here the columns are next to each other so we can get index of `'flag'` columns and use `-1` to get corresponding columns.

```
flag_cols <- grep('flag', names(df))
inds <- df[flag_cols] != "G"
df[flag_cols][inds] <- NA
df[flag_cols - 1][inds] <- NA
df

#                 date pm2.5 pm2.5_flag NEPH NEPH_flag NEPH_RH NEPH_RH_flag
#1  2020-02-0400:00:00  26.8          G 1.02         G    35.8            G
#2  2020-02-0400:01:00    NA       <NA>   NA      <NA>    35.7            G
#10 2020-02-0400:09:00    NA       <NA> 0.72         G    35.0            G
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this with `split.default`

```
df1[-1] <- do.call(cbind,  lapply(split.default(df1[-1], 
         cumsum(!grepl('flag', names(df1)[-1]))),
                function(x) {
           x[x[[2]] != 'G', ] <- NA
         x}))
df1
#                  date pm2.5 pm2.5_flag NEPH NEPH_flag NEPH_RH NEPH_RH_flag
#1  2020-02-04 00:00:00  26.8          G 1.02         G    35.8            G
#2  2020-02-04 00:01:00    NA       <NA>   NA      <NA>    35.7            G
#10 2020-02-04 00:09:00    NA       <NA> 0.72         G    35.0            G
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("2020-02-04 00:00:00", "2020-02-04 00:01:00", 
"2020-02-04 00:09:00"), pm2.5 = c(26.8, 27.1, 27.8), pm2.5_flag = c("G", 
"C", "C"), NEPH = c(1.02, 0.98, 0.72), NEPH_flag = c("G", "BIA", 
"G"), NEPH_RH = c(35.8, 35.7, 35), NEPH_RH_flag = c("G", "G", 
"G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "10"))
```